# Using Webpage to run exe on Localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, localhost

I am trying to use a webpage that I have on iis localhost to run an executable but it refuses to work. It works just fine if I run the webpage using visual studio. I have tried changing the permissions of the folder where the executable is located giving full access to the DefaultAppPool. I've tried changing the settings in the DefaultAppPool to enable 32bit apps and also changing the Identity to LocalSystem. I have allowed the IIS Admin Service to interact with desktop. None of these things has worked.

This is what I have for the code. Any help whatsoever will be greatly appreciated.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int port = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text);
    string ipaddress = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
    string event_type = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text;

    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot";
        startInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot", "ConsoleAppField.exe");
        startInfo.Verb = "runas";
        //MLHIDE
        startInfo.Arguments = ipaddress + " " + port + " " + event_type;
        startInfo.ErrorDialog = true;

        Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
        process.WaitForExit();
        //return process.ExitCode;
    }
    catch (Win32Exception ex)
    {

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //WriteLog(ex);
        //return ErrorReturnInteger;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Is it throwing an Exception?

Comment: Have you tried just Process.Start("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ConsoleAppField.exe"); This works for me.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: Do you own the source code for this exe? If so, it'd probably be better to turn that into a class library you call directly, or to turn it into a service that you can call using some inter-process communication. Controlling exe's from a web service is going to be very brittle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Process.Start() and passing in your arguments like so,

```
Process.Start("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ConsoleAppField.exe", ipaddress + " " + port + " " + event_type);
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. All it did was cause the page to reload.

Comment: @DillanoBlake This works for me on ASP.net, Sorry I could not help.